Is there a way to simplify the multiselect query in the google sheets?
The source file contains 17k to 20k rows.
I'm struggling with the speed of calculating, the sheet is unresponsive for 60+ seconds. There are 14 executions of this function per sheet, and 6 sheets exist.
I've tried doing it with a filter function and it is super slow.
=FILTER({
{Source!B2:B,Source!R2:S};
{Source!B2:B,Source!T2:U};
{Source!B2:B,Source!V2:W};
{Source!B2:B,Source!X2:Y};
{Source!B2:B,Source!Z2:AA};
{Source!B2:B,Source!AB2:AC};
{Source!B2:B,Source!AD2:AE};
{Source!B2:B,Source!AF2:AG};
{Source!B2:B,Source!AH2:AI};
{Source!B2:B,Source!AJ2:AK};
{Source!B2:B,Source!AL2:AM};
{Source!B2:B,Source!AN2:AO}
},
{Source!R2:R;Source!T2:T;Source!V2:V;Source!X2:X;Source!Z2:Z;Source!AB2:AB;Source!AD2:AD;Source!AF2:AF;Source!AH2:AH;Source!AJ2:AJ;Source!AL2:AL;Source!AN2:AN}=$B$1,
{Source!B2:B;Source!B2:B;Source!B2:B;Source!B2:B;Source!B2:B;Source!B2:B;Source!B2:B;Source!B2:B;Source!B2:B;Source!B2:B;Source!B2:B;Source!B2:B}=$B$2)

Then I tried with a Query, this works, but it is still slow as it is, and unfinished
={QUERY(
QUERY(
Source!A2:AO,"SELECT B,R,S WHERE B='"&B2&"'"),"SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3 WHERE Col2='"&B1&"'");
QUERY(QUERY(Source!A2:AO,"SELECT B,T,U WHERE B='"&B2&"'"),"SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3 WHERE Col2='"&B1&"'");
QUERY(QUERY(Source!A2:AO,"SELECT B,V,W WHERE B='"&B2&"'"),"SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3 WHERE Col2='"&B1&"'")}

The last thing that I've tried to mess with is this, but it works only for the first set:
=QUERY(
QUERY(
Source!A2:AO,"SELECT B,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,AA,AB,AC,AD,AE,AF,AG,AH,AI,AJ,AK,AL,AM,AN,AO WHERE B='"&B2&"'"),
{("SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3 WHERE Col2='"&B1&"'");
("SELECT Col1,Col4,Col5 WHERE Col4='"&B1&"'");
("SELECT Col1,Col6,Col7 WHERE Col6='"&B1&"'");
("SELECT Col1,Col8,Col9 WHERE Col8='"&B1&"'");
("SELECT Col1,Col9,Col10 WHERE Col10='"&B1&"'");
("SELECT Col1,Col11,Col12 WHERE Col12='"&B1&"'")
})

The requirement does not look complicated, my knowledge of the subject is a bit limited. Any help is appreciated.
I cannot provide a shared sheet, I'm really sorry.
The expected result needs to be:



Column A
Column B
Column C




data 1
Text 1
RndNumber1


data 1
Text 1
RndNumber2


data 1
Text 1
RndNumber3


data 1
Text 1
RndNumber2


data 1
Text 1
RndNumber4




try loading ranges only once:
=LET(b,Source!B2:B,
 r,OFFSET(b,,16,,2),
 t,OFFSET(b,,18,,2),
 v,OFFSET(b,,20,,2),
 x,OFFSET(b,,22,,2),
 z,OFFSET(b,,24,,2),
ab,OFFSET(b,,26,,2),
ad,OFFSET(b,,28,,2),
af,OFFSET(b,,30,,2),
ah,OFFSET(b,,32,,2),
aj,OFFSET(b,,34,,2),
al,OFFSET(b,,36,,2),
an,OFFSET(b,,38,,2), 
FILTER({{b;b;b;b;b;b;b;b;b;b;b;b}, {r;t;v;x;z;ab;ad;af;ah;aj;al;an}},
$B$2={b;b;b;b;b;b;b;b;b;b;b;b},
$B$1={INDEX(r,,1);INDEX(t,,1);INDEX(v,,1);INDEX(x,,1);INDEX(z,,1);INDEX(ab,,1);INDEX(ad,,1);INDEX(af,,1);INDEX(ah,,1);INDEX(aj,,1);INDEX(al,,1);INDEX(an,,1)}))


update:
instead of building array of 12 × 20k = 240k rows let's do double filter-down. first from 20k rows to x rows and then from x rows to final output:
=LET(x, WRAPROWS(TOROW(FILTER(Source!R2:AO, Source!B2:B=B2),,), 2), 
 FILTER({IF(INDEX(x,,1)="",,B2), x}, INDEX(x,,1)=B1))



@Djisin answer updated. try now

The Solution accepted! The time is simply incomparable. It takes about 6-10 seconds for a whole sheet. Thank you so much! <3


Here's one approach you may test out:
 =let(Σ,reduce(,sequence(12,1,1,2),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,hstack(Source!B2:B,choosecols(Source!R2:AO,sequence(2,1,c)))))),
 filter(Σ,index(Σ,,2)=B1,index(Σ,,1)=B2))

I can't vouch for any speed improvement or so! I just winged a simplified version of your formula logic.

Wow, that worked perfectly from the first try. I will apply it to one sheet to check the times. Can you please explain roughly how it works?

reduce/lambda vertically stacks columns B,R,S in first go → B,T,U in second go → .... → B,AN,AO in the last go. the number of go's are defined by the given logic sequence(12,1,1,2)

It works good up to 6 executions, I'm guessing because there are less occurrences of the matching sets. The speed is similar to the Filter when on full sheet. Thanks for trying <3

Now that is used a stopwatch, filter does a full sheet comparison in 36 seconds, and this one in 81 :(
